# How can I run Cube 3D Amination?

Tags: html, css, animation

With clone coding, I coded a cube to rotate when a button was clicked.
(However, since it is still in the learning stage, JS is not used, only HTML and CCS are used.)
**I wanted an angle to look down on the box slightly from above**, but the result is implemented only by viewing it from the center of the cube front.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  line-height: 1.618em;
  color: #444;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 50rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  text-align: center;  
}

.prespective {
  perspective: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  perspective-origin: 25rem-150px;
}
.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 3.5rem auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* animation: rotate 10s infinite linear; */
}
.cube div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  opacity: 0.95;
}

.cube div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}
.front {
  transform: translateZ(200px);
}
.back {
  transform: translateZ(-200px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
}


input {
  display: none;
}

#rotate:checked ~ .cube{
  animation: rotate 10s infinite linear;
}

#back:checked ~ .cube{
  animation: none;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#front:checked ~ .cube{
  animation:none;
  transform:none;
}

#right:checked ~ .cube{
  animation:none;
  transform:rotateY(-90deg);
}

#left:checked ~ .cube{
  animation:none;
  transform:rotateY(90deg);
}

#top:checked ~ .cube{
  animation:none;
  transform:rotateX(-90deg);
}

#bottom:checked ~ .cube{
  animation:none;
  transform:rotateX(90deg);
}

label{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em ;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background: darkgreen; color: #fff; margin: 0. 0.25rem; 
  transition: 0.25s;
  
}

input:checked + label{
  background: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rotatable 3D Cube</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>


  <div class="wrapper">

  <div class="perspective">

    <input type="radio" id="rotate" name="switch"/>
    <label for="rotate">auto</label>

    <input type="radio" id="front" name="switch"/>
    <label for="front">front</label>

    <input type="radio" id="left" name="switch"/>
    <label for="left">left</label>

    <input type="radio" id="back" name="switch"/>
    <label for="back">back</label>

    <input type="radio" id="right" name="switch"/>
    <label for="right">right</label>

    <input type="radio" id="top" name="switch"/>
    <label for="top">top</label>

    <input type="radio" id="bottom" name="switch"/>
    <label for="bottom">bottom</label>


    <div class="cube">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/front.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/back.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="top">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/top.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/bottom.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="left">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/left.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/right.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

**

[image: My coding result Cube angle]

[image: The angle I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a wrapper that is rotated and keeps the perspective like your cube. I've created a quick example similar to your screenshot provided.

The only thing I've added is `cubeWrapper` as a new class and DOM Element and included it into your selectors so they stay valid.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  line-height: 1.618em;
  color: #444;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 50rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  text-align: center;  
}

.prespective {
  perspective: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  perspective-origin: ca;c(25rem - 150px);
}
.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 3.5rem auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /* animation: rotate 10s infinite linear; */
}
.cube div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  opacity: 0.95;
}

.cube div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}

.cubeWrapper {
  perspective: 1200px;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(200px);
}
.back {
  transform: translateZ(-200px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
}


input {
  display: none;
}

#rotate:checked ~ .cubeWrapper .cube{
  animation: rotate 10s infinite linear;
}

#back:checked ~ .cubeWrapper .cube{
  animation: none;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#front:checked ~ .cubeWrapper .cube{
  animation:none;
  transform:none;
}

#right:checked ~ .cubeWrapper .cube{
  animation:none;
  transform:rotateY(-90deg);
}

#left:checked ~ .cubeWrapper .cube{
  animation:none;
  transform:rotateY(90deg);
}

#top:checked ~ .cubeWrapper .cube{
  animation:none;
  transform:rotateX(-90deg);
}

#bottom:checked ~ .cubeWrapper .cube{
  animation:none;
  transform:rotateX(90deg);
}

label{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em ;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background: darkgreen; color: #fff; margin: 0. 0.25rem; 
  transition: 0.25s;
  
}

input:checked + label{
  background: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rotatable 3D Cube</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>


  <div class="wrapper">

  <div class="perspective">

    <input type="radio" id="rotate" name="switch"/>
    <label for="rotate">auto</label>

    <input type="radio" id="front" name="switch"/>
    <label for="front">front</label>

    <input type="radio" id="left" name="switch"/>
    <label for="left">left</label>

    <input type="radio" id="back" name="switch"/>
    <label for="back">back</label>

    <input type="radio" id="right" name="switch"/>
    <label for="right">right</label>

    <input type="radio" id="top" name="switch"/>
    <label for="top">top</label>

    <input type="radio" id="bottom" name="switch"/>
    <label for="bottom">bottom</label>

  <div class="cubeWrapper">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/front.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/back.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="top">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/top.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/bottom.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="left">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/left.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <img src="https://smilecmk.github.io/hosted-assets/images/right.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>

  </div>

</div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Timothy Alexis Vass. I solved the problem!